# How do I add a 1dp line to the bottom of my textview cell ( not a table layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent, android-emulator

I am new to android, jsut a very plain simple question, how do i add a bottom line to a text view, so that it appears at the bottom of the cell as 1dp, here's the code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_str"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/manage_categories"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto-Regular"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
```

line_str.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item>
  <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />
  </shape>
</item>
<!-- This is the line -->
<item android:bottom="1dp">
 <shape>
       <solid android:color="#252525" />
 </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd put a horizontally expanding 9patch image and add it to drawableBottom property of the textview.

As for the layer-list approach try this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item>
  <shape>
        <size android:height="@dimen/textViewHeight"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />
  </shape>
</item>
<!-- This is the line -->
<item android:top="@dimen/textViewHeight">
 <shape>
       <size android:height="1dp"/>
       <solid android:color="#252525" />
 </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: what is @dimen/textviewheight?

Comment: this would be your declaration of the height of the textView in the dimens.xml folder. Or you can hardcode the value right here itself.